# @PreAuthorize Controller invalidates @Inject in @InitBinder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-validator

In a simple controller :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

  private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  @Inject
  private MyValidator myValidator;

  @InitBinder("myObj")
  private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    logger.info("myValidator = {}", myValidator);
    binder.initDirectFieldAccess();
    binder.setValidator(myValidator);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/doPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String doPost(MyObj myObj , BindingResult br ) throws IOException {
    logger.info("myObj = {} , bindingResult = {}" , myObj , br);
    return "redirect:/test/form";
  }
}
```

I noticed the injected validator is always null in the `initBinder` method , the logger is even null (and throws NPE) , this is weird.

If I totally remove the  `@InitBinder initBinder()` method , the `myValidator` is available (not null) again in each method.

After eliminating many factors , I found the culprit is the `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")` . After removing this `@PreAuthorize` , everything works fine.

Is it a bug ? Does something conflicts with SpringSecurity and SpringValidation and SpringMVC ?

How to fix it ?

environments :

```
<spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<springboot.version>1.3.0.M5</springboot.version>
<spring-security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You wrote: "the logger is even null"... that is so weird that I believe that there is something else going wrong (build process...). Try to use `private final Logger ...` (with `final`). Then the logger must been not null. If it is still null, then search for this problem somewhere else, but not in the frameworks. - One thing that came in my mind is AspectJ or any other technic used to by `@PreAuthorize` to apply its functionality.

Comment: Hi , even add `final` , the logger is still null in the `@InitBinder` method. The only solution is to make it static.

Comment: That's most likely due to proxying. Using Spring Security on Controllers is not a good practice. If you have to restrict requests restrict URLs. The services are the ones that should be annotated. Field injection is a bad practice too. Use constructor injection instead.

Comment: @zeroflagL not matter if it is good or bad practice (not allowed to discuss with stack overlfow questions) , it should work.

Comment: Hi , after reporting to Spring's JIRA , it seems Spring's team has taken it as a bug : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13580

Comment: @Ralph Sure. Why do things right if it should work anyway ... Read my comment again. I'm confident you'll find the assumed cause for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was to create a setter method for `myValidator`. this setter is then called when the app initializes. Do this for all the injectables that are being nullified by @PreAuthorize tags.